# CTE is returning an empty set

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with MySQL/DBeaver to calculate the growth rate between 2 quarters using 2 CTE.

As simple queries, the 2 CTE are working :

`select count(*) as vente_trim1 from mutation where date_mutation <='2020-03-31';`

`select count(*) as vente_trim2 from mutation where date_mutation >='2020-04-01';`

But I get an empty set when using them as CTE in this query:

```
with 
table_trim1 as (select count(*) as vente_trim1 
                from mutation 
                where date_mutation <='2020-03-31'),
table_trim2 as (select count(*) as vente_trim2 
                from mutation 
                where date_mutation >='2020-04-01')
select vente_trim1, vente_trim2, 
       ((vente_trim2-vente_trim1)/vente_trim1*100) as evolution
from table_trim1
join table_trim2 on vente_trim1=vente_trim2;
```

Attached is a screenshot of the empty set.

What am I doing wrong? I am very new to SQL, so any help would be appreciated.

[screenshot_query_CTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSP6z.jpg)

Edit:
I have now a working query for the growth rate column:

```
select
(((select count(*) from mutation 
where date_mutation >='2020-04-01')
-
(select count(*) from mutation 
where date_mutation <='2020-03-31'))
/
(select count(*) from mutation 
where date_mutation <='2020-03-31')*100)
as evolution;
```

To make it clearer, what I am trying to get is this:

| vente_trim1 | vente_trim2 | evolution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16831 | 17338 | 3,0123 |

Comment: I guess, in this case you need CROSS JOIN :from table_trim1
CROSS join table_trim2

Comment: Do you really expect the two counts to be the same?

Comment: As @Sergey stated, you need a cartesian product between 2 dataset. You also talk about semesters but your filters are quite weird... Maybe your data fits with the filter of semesters that you are doing, but in a first sight they seem wrong

Comment: Sorry I meant quarters not semesters, I just edited my post accordingly

Comment: @jarlh They are different: count of the 1st quarter is 16831 and count of the 2nd quarter is 17338

Comment: @Sergey I tried CROSS JOIN and the set is still empty

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide the query text with cross join

Comment: @Sergey 'with 
table_trim1 as (select count(*) as vente_trim1 
from mutation 
where date_mutation <='2020-03-31'),
table_trim2 as (select count(*) as vente_trim2 
from mutation 
where date_mutation >='2020-04-01')
select vente_trim1, vente_trim2, 
((vente_trim2-vente_trim1)/vente_trim1*100) as evolution
from table_trim1
cross join table_trim2 on vente_trim1=vente_trim2;'

Comment: with table_trim1 as (select count() as vente_trim1 from mutation where date_mutation <='2020-03-31'), table_trim2 as (select count() as vente_trim2 from mutation where date_mutation >='2020-04-01') select vente_trim1, vente_trim2, ((vente_trim2-vente_trim1)/vente_trim1*100) as evolution from table_trim1 cross join table_trim2

Comment: When you're asking for help, please don't post screenshots or photographs. Cut & paste the text into the reddit message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: @Sergey I tried your query, it still gives me an error. I edited my original post with more details if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(date_mutation <= '2020-03-31') as vente_trim1,
       sum(date_mutation >= '2020-04-01') as vente_trim2
from mutation ;
```

The problem with your query is that it only returns rows when the two counts are equal.

Comment: I need to calculate the growth rate between the count of 1st quarter and 2 quarter, not between the sums. When replacing sum by count in the query you gave me, it gives me the 2 wanted columns, but the results is the same on both columns (34169 which is the total of the 2 counts). Also, I am missing a 3rd column for the growth rate.

Comment: @valerieR . . . The `sum()` *is* counting the values in each quarter.

Comment: You're right, but now I am very confused. I thought count() was counting values and sum() was adding values. Why in this case is sum counting instead of adding?

Comment: @valerieR . . . `sum(1)` and `count(1)` return the same value.  I'm not saying that is what is happening here.  You need to think through what the operations are doing.